# Get name of last created folder on windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line

Is it possible to get the name of the last created folder in a variable on the windows command line?

Preferably natively, without using Cygwin etc. What I'm looking for is to run some command/batch script which gives me the LastCreatedDir for the path in which I currently am

Comment: replace the `mkdir` executable with a script that updates a `%lastDirCreated%` variable perhaps?

Comment: Ummm, the issue in that case will be I'll be able to have just 1 global 'lastDirCreated'. What I'm looking for is to run some command/batch script which gives me the LastCreatedDir for the path in which I currently am.

Comment: That is an issue; not an issue outlined in the question, though. You could always keep a registry/service of them. Seems like a lot of overhead, but would be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from a batch file:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /O:-D /A:D /T:c /B') DO (
@set yourvariable=%%G 
exit /b
)
```